# VC Bug? Non-constexpr Function Template Evaluated as constexpr

Tags: c++11, constexpr, visual-c++-2015

*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3*
 does not issue errors when compiling the [code below](http://rextester.com/RPDQX68594). Am I missing something?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

template < class T > constexpr T oops( T s )
{
  std::cout << s; // ignored - no code is generated
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  static_assert( oops( 1 ) == 1, "!" ); // non-constant condition not detected
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C++14 rules seem to allow it? Not positive on that. But it's the programmer's fault for using side-effect functions, which won't be executed during compilation.

Comment: Seems like either Clang or VS2015 must be wrong here. But which one?

Comment: @ZanLynx It does not seem like a feature. I have filled a bug form at Microsoft, but it usually takes weeks/months to get an answer.

Comment: @Muscampester CLang and GCC behave in the same way. VC must be wrong, but it is hard to believe that Microsoft did not test such a simple construct.